# Proper way to change language on website?

Tags: django, html

I'm doing a website and would like to include language change. What is the proper way to handle this ? Just copy html's, rename and translate them and change links ? Or is there a better way ? I'm using django.

**Edit:**
Here are some good tutorials for anyone interested:
Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/
Easy start: https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/quick-guide-django-i18n/

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django offers settings to automatically update language options:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/

Django also has a full page on [Internationalization](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n) (i.e. [I18N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization#Naming)) and [Localization](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n) (i.e. [L10N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization#Naming)):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

Several topics are covered, one of which is:

- [Translation of Text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/)

You will need to update your template files if they are not properly configured for translation:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import gettext

def my_view(request):
    output = gettext("Welcome to my site.")
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. That's what I was looking for. I read a bit about it and look like it's rather easy to do localization with django.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the option of using google translate to automatically translate your website to every lang https://translate.google.com/manager/website/.

Another option is to add a lang attribute to every text, and having all text a few times for etch lang. then using a javascript script to detect the user's lang like this :

```
navigator.userLanguage
```

and removing all text that don't have the right lang attribute.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to translate but manualy do it. Look like it is a lot of work to do it with js. Thansk for reply.